# Limit the Primefaces datePicker hour, minutes and seconds to given values

Tags: javascript, java, primefaces

I am using a datePicker Primefaces element in order to allow the user to select a value for the hours, minutes and seconds. Currently, the hour has values between 0 and 24, the minutes are between 0 and 60 and same for the seconds.

I want to limit this possibility of choice to some static values, obtained from getting the length of a video posted on the page.

So, for example, if the video has 1 minute and 30 seconds, I want the hours part not to allow the user to press the arrow up or down, the minutes to be maximum 30 and the minutes 1.
I tried the below code, but it does not work - I manage to see the max length of the video when I enter the page, but if I move the arrows from the datePicker element, I can select anything.

What can I do?

The UI datePicker element:

```
<p:outputPanel styleClass="input-group timestamp-input">
                                <p:datePicker id="timeDatePicker"
                                              widgetVar="widgetVarOfDatePicker"
                                              value="#{traineeDashboard.newIncidentTimestamp}"
                                              timeOnly="true"
                                              showSeconds="true"
                                              appendTo="@this">
                                    <f:converter converterId="timeConverter"/>
                                </p:datePicker>
```

JS Code:

```
function setMaxTimeForDatePicker(hours, minutes, seconds) {
    var timePicker = PF('widgetVarOfDatePicker'); 
    var hoursDropdown = $('div.ui-hour-picker span:eq(1)');
    var minutesDropdown = $('div.ui-minute-picker span:eq(1)');
    var secondsDropdown = $('div.ui-second-picker span:eq(1)');

    hoursDropdown.text(hours);
    minutesDropdown.text(minutes);
    secondsDropdown.text(seconds);

    hoursDropdown.trigger('change');
    minutesDropdown.trigger('change');
    secondsDropdown.trigger('change');
}

$(function() {
    var timePicker = PF('widgetVarOfDatePicker'); // Replace with your actual widgetVar

    // Override the behaviors for incrementing and decrementing hours, minutes, and seconds
    timePicker.cfg.onHourChange = function(newHour) {
        let maxHour = 2;
        let minHour = 0;
        if (newHour < minHour || newHour > maxHour) {
            // Set the hour back to the minimum or maximum as appropriate
            this.setTime(minHour, this.currentMinute, this.currentSecond);
        }
    };

    timePicker.cfg.onMinuteChange = function(newMinute) {
        if (newMinute < minMinute || newMinute > maxMinute) {
            // Set the minute back to the minimum or maximum as appropriate
            this.setTime(this.currentHour, minMinute, this.currentSecond);
        }
    };

    timePicker.cfg.onSecondChange = function(newSecond) {
        if (newSecond < minSecond || newSecond > maxSecond) {
            // Set the second back to the minimum or maximum as appropriate
            this.setTime(this.currentHour, this.currentMinute, minSecond);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `minDate` and `maxDate` attributes of the `p:datePicker` component. Since you want to limit the time (hours, minutes, seconds), you can set the `minDate` and `maxDate` to the same date, but with different times.

First, you need to create a `java.util.Date` object with the maximum time you want to allow. You can do this by creating a `java.util.Calendar` object, setting the hours, minutes, and seconds, and then getting the `java.util.Date` object.

Example;

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, maxHour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, maxMinute);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, maxSecond);
Date maxTime = calendar.getTime();
```

Then, you set this `Date` object to the `maxDate` attribute of the `p:datePicker` component.

In the above code, `traineeDashboard.minDate` and `traineeDashboard.maxTime` are the `Date` objects that you created in your managed bean.

This way, the user will not be able to select a time that is outside the range you specified.

Remember to set the `minDate` and `maxDate` attributes to the same date, but with different times. For example, if you want to allow a time range from 00:00:00 to 01:30:00, you can set the `minDate` to 00:00:00 and the `maxDate` to 01:30:00.

Also, note that the `minDate` and `maxDate` attributes accept `java.util.Date` objects, not `java.time.LocalDateTime` or `java.time.LocalTime` objects. If you're using `java.time` classes, you can convert them to `java.util.Date` objects using the `java.sql.Timestamp` class or the `java.time.Instant` class.

Comment: Thank you for the response, it looks good at first, but it seems like I cannot get a Date object in java without an actual date: it always contains either today s date or 1st of January 1970 and due to this, it gives an error